# How to flip a texture within beginNativePainting()?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures, qglwidget

I'm writing a class that inherits from **QGLWidget**:

```
class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~GLWidget();

    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);    

private:
    QImage* _frame;
};
```

The constructor of `GLWidget` loads an image from the disk, and `paintEvent()` is responsible to send the data to the GPU using native OpenGL calls that are executed between `beginNativePainting()` and `endNativePainting()`, and this works OK.

The problem is that the image is being displayed flipped (vertically), and I need to fix this. I haven't found a way to this so I'm hoping somebody can help me on this issue.

In a native Glut application I could simply call `glFrustum()` like this to do the flip:

```
static void Reshape( int width, int height )
{
   glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );

   glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
   glLoadIdentity();

   glFrustum( -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 10.0, 100.0 );  // flip vertically

   glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
   glLoadIdentity();
   glTranslatef( 0.0, 0.0, -15.0 );
}
```

But I've tried loading the projection matrix after the `beginNativePainting()` and calling `glFrustum()` with the same values as the call above and all I get is a black screen (which means it didn't worked as expected).

Any tips?

Also, using the `mirrowed(false, true)` method of `QImage` to do the flipping didn't had any effect in the displaying of the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't flip the projection, mirror the texture coordinates.

BTW: OpenGL assumes the origin of texture image data in the lower left corner (contrary to most windowing systems, which have it in the upper left).

Comment: @karlphillip: I can's as long as you don't give me your code in which you draw the texture. It depends on this.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now I know what I have to do. I just tested it and it worked.